# Detect if a div is in certain part of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the site im working on I want users to be scroll and click on icons to "open" them up.For example if a user clicks the about us icon it would have a paragraph of info in which they can scroll up and down the text along with a back button. the back button would take the user back to the icon where they can scroll once more to pick another icon.I was wondering how can i have my underscore icon be detected when its on the screen (not when its clicked)? Im using slots JS for the animation and i cant figure out how to detect if its in on the screen.

**Ive tried this :**

```
function isOnScreen(){
  console.log($("#theMiddle").height());
  if (($("#middleID").offset().top + $("#middleID").height()) >=     $("#theMiddle").height()) {
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

```js
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
//the key strokes for the up and down keys
// Set up our container
var el = document.querySelector("#theMiddle");
// Create new SlotMachine
var slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});

function isOnScreen(){
  console.log($("#theMiddle").height());
  if (($("#middleID").offset().top + $("#middleID").height()) >= $("#theMiddle").height()) {
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

function open() {
    anime({
        targets: "div.right",
        translateX: {
            value: 200,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
    anime({
        targets: "div.left",
        translateX: {
            value: -200,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
}



document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == "40") {
        //this is down
        //this will open it up
        open();
        console.log(isOnScreen());
        slot.prev();
    } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
        open();
        console.log(isOnScreen());
        slot.next();
    }

}

//Scroll detection occurs here, without the scrollbar
$("html").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    open();
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (delta < 0) {
        //This is for the scrolling down
        // animation opens up the brakets
        slot.prev();
    }
    if (delta > 0) {
        slot.next();
    }
});


//this is for detecting clicks  for the divs in the middle div
// 1 = the 2nd image , 2 = the  3rd image
$(".middle div").click(function() {
    if ($(this).index() == '1') {
        $('#theMiddle').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $('#aboutTextID').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            $("#backButtonID").fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            //Define the event handler here after the btn has been created
            $("#backButtonID").click(function() {
                console.log("back");
                $('#aboutTextID').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#backButtonID").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $('#theMiddle').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    if ($(this).index() == '2') {
        $('#theMiddle').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $('#applyButtonID').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            $("#backButtonID").fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            //Define the event handler here after the btn has been created
            $("#backButtonID").click(function() {
                console.log("back");
                $('#applyButtonID').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#backButtonID").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $('#theMiddle').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;

}

div.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 390px;
}

div.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}

div.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 870px;
}

#left,#right{
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#middle{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
#theMiddle{
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

#aboutTextID{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.backButton{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 90px;
}
#applyButtonID{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  left: 600px;
  top:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Underscores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" name="Back" class="backButton" id="backButtonID">Back</button>


  <div id= "left" class="left">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <p id='aboutTextID' >"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </p>

<a id="applyButtonID" class="typeform-share button" href="https://bhagyeshpatel1.typeform.com/to/ytfEgw" data-mode="popup" style="text-decoration:none;background-color:#662c92;color:white;cursor:pointer;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:50px;text-align:center;margin:0;height:50px;padding:0px 33px;border-radius:25px;max-width:100%;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;font-weight:bold;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;" \
target="_blank">Launch me </a>
<script> (function() {
  var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm_share", b="https://embed.typeform.com/";
    if(!gi.call(d,id)){
      js=ce.call(d,"script");
      js.id=id;
      js.src=b+"embed.js";
      q=gt.call(d,"script")[0];
      q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) }
    })()
</script>
  <div class="middle" id = "theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt="" class="icons" id="aboutID"></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt="" class="icons" id="jobID"></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
  </div>

  <div id= "right" class="right"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" alt=""></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the position of an element you can use `getBoundingClientRect()`

Example:

```
var div = document.getElementById("example");
var left = div.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var top = div.getBoundingClientRect().top;
alert("X position: " + left + ", Y position: " + top);
```